# DateTime nullable exception as a parameter

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, parameters, null

I have a Search Form that can search by a few different fields.  The problem field is birthDate.  On the form it is a string.  In the SQL 2005 db it is a DateTime that can be null.

The code below is sequential as far as declaring the variable on the form and then setting it.  Then the call to the BLL and then the call to the DAL.

On this line -->

```
dgvSearchResults.DataSource =ConnectBLL.BLL.Person.Search(_firstName,_middleName,_lastName,_sSN, (DateTime)_birthDate,_applicationID,_applicationPersonID,_fuzzy);
```

I am getting a *"Nullable object must have value"* error.

I assume because I didn't give a Date param and then tried to Cast to a non-nullable DateTime.  Correct?

What can I do about it?  There has to be a way around it.  This exact same BLL & DAL work on the web app version.

### EDIT 1

A few things to note.  I was under the impression that `DateTime?` was the same as `Nullable<DateTime>` Correct?

Also,  I don't see how I can put in an arbitrary value for a field like BirthDate.  I suppose I could build in a bunch of filters in my business layer but that seems tho "Hack" way.  Maybe not.  Also, it bothers me that this same BLL and DAL with this same DB allow nulls in the BirthDate field in the WebApp version of this program.  Any ideas there?  The DB has *null* in it for those entries with out a date.

***Search.cs***

```
public DateTime? _birthDate;
_birthDate = null;
if (datBirthDate.Text != string.Empty)
    _birthDate = Convert.ToDateTime(datBirthDate.Text);
dgvSearchResults.DataSource=ConnectBLL.BLL.Person.Search(_firstName,_middleName,_lastName,_sSN, (DateTime)_birthDate,_applicationID,_applicationPersonID,_fuzzy);
```

***ConnectBLL --> Person.vb***

```
Public Shared Function Search(ByVal firstName As String, ByVal middleName As String, ByVal lastName As String, ByVal SSN As String, ByVal birthDate As Date, ByVal applicationId As Integer, ByVal applicationPersonId As String, ByVal fuzzy As Boolean) As Data.DataTable
Try
    Dim tbl As Data.DataTable = DAL.Connect.SearchPerson(firstName, middleName, lastName, SSN, birthDate, applicationId, applicationPersonId, fuzzy)

    If tbl.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        tbl.DefaultView.Sort = "Last Name ASC, First Name ASC, Middle Name ASC"
    End If
    Return tbl
Catch
    Throw
End Try
```

End Function

***ConnectDAL --> Connect.vb***

```
Public Shared Function SearchPerson(ByVal _FirstName As String, ByVal _MiddleName As String, ByVal _LastName As String, ByVal _SSN As String, ByVal _BirthDate As Date, ByVal _ApplicationID As Integer, ByVal _ApplicationPersonID As String, ByVal _Fuzzy As Boolean) As Data.DataTable
Dim test As New clsSqlResponseTime
Dim dt As New Data.DataTable
Try
    Using cnn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConnectROConnectionString)
        Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand()
        cmd.Connection = cnn
        If _Fuzzy Then
            cmd.CommandText = strSearchPersonFuzzyStoredProcedure
        Else
            cmd.CommandText = strSearchPersonStoredProcedure
        End If
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        If Not IsNothing(_FirstName) Then cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@FirstName", _FirstName))
        If Not IsNothing(_MiddleName) Then cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@MiddleName", _MiddleName))
        If Not IsNothing(_LastName) Then cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@LastName", _LastName))
        If Not IsNothing(_SSN) Then cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@SSN", _SSN))
        If Not (_BirthDate = Date.MinValue) Then cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@BirthDate", _BirthDate))
        If Not IsNothing(_ApplicationPersonID) Then cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@ApplicationID", _ApplicationID))
        If Not IsNothing(_ApplicationPersonID) Then cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@ApplicationPersonID", _ApplicationPersonID))

        Dim da As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        da.Fill(dt)
    End Using
Catch
    Throw
End Try
test.Log("SearchPerson", "Connect")
Return dt
```

End Function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to me that you're not using the birthDate value at all until the third function, where it's being added to a Parameters collection.  In that third function it's already being tested against Date.MinValue before adding it.  Simply change the first function to this:

```
public DateTime _birthDate;
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(datBirthDate.Text))
    _birthDate = DateTime.MinValue;
else
    _birthDate = Convert.ToDateTime(datBirthDate.Text);
dgvSearchResults.DataSource=ConnectBLL.BLL.Person.Search(_firstName,_middleName,_lastName,_sSN,_birthDate,_applicationID,_applicationPersonID,_fuzzy);
```

That's the easiest way out, but not necessarily the most correct.  I would change all three functions to use a Nullable DateTime like so:

Function 1

```
public DateTime? _birthDate = null;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(datBirthDate.Text))
    _birthDate = Convert.ToDateTime(datBirthDate.Text);
dgvSearchResults.DataSource=ConnectBLL.BLL.Person.Search(_firstName,_middleName,_lastName,_sSN,_birthDate,_applicationID,_applicationPersonID,_fuzzy);
```

Function 2 and 3 definitions should look like:

```
Public Shared Function Search(ByVal firstName As String, ByVal middleName As String, ByVal lastName As String, ByVal SSN As String, ByVal birthDate As Nullable(Of Date), ByVal applicationId As Integer, ByVal applicationPersonId As String, ByVal fuzzy As Boolean) As Data.DataTable

Public Shared Function SearchPerson(ByVal _FirstName As String, ByVal _MiddleName As String, ByVal _LastName As String, ByVal _SSN As String, ByVal _BirthDate As Nullable(Of Date), ByVal _ApplicationID As Integer, ByVal _ApplicationPersonID As String, ByVal _Fuzzy As Boolean) As Data.DataTable
```

And the line in Function 3 that uses the birthDate:

```
If (_BirthDate.HasValue) Then cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@BirthDate", _BirthDate.Value))
```

Comment: Yes, your first function is currently defining _birthDate as a Nullable DateTime.  But you're not properly treating it as such by explicitly casting it back to a DateTime.  If you need the underlying DateTime from the nullable, first check the HasValue property and then use the Value property to get the DateTime.  Note that Value will throw an InvalidOperationException if HasValue is false.

Comment: Thank you.  I am still stumped as to why this isn't a problem in the Web App but this helped me get my WinForm version going.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
dgvSearchResults.DataSource=ConnectBLL.BLL.Person.Search(_firstName,_middleName,_lastName,_sSN, _birthDate.HasValue ? _birthDate.Value : new DateTime() ,_applicationID,_applicationPersonID,_fuzzy);
```

Basically, if it's null, just default it to whatever the default of DateTime is (I believe it's 1/1/0001).

Comment: I tried something similar to this but 1/1/0001 is not compatible with SQL's default.

Answer (score 1):

You look like you are attempting to cast a possible Null value to DateTime in Search.cs on this line.

dgvSearchResults.DataSource=ConnectBLL.BLL.Person.Search(_firstName,_middleName,_lastName,_sSN, (DateTime)_birthDate,_applicationID,_applicationPersonID,_fuzzy);

That would cause this error. If the string is empty you will cast null to DateTime which would blow up. I suggest your Person.Search method take Nullable<DateTime> as the parameter and handle the null case there or set it to DateTime.MinValue and treat that as null in Person.Search.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting _birthDate to null, why not set it with some DateTime value? That way it can't be null being passed to the BLL call. Either DateTime.MinValue or DateTime.Now can work.

Comment: won't i have Data Integrity issues then?  Giving people invalid birthdates?